# target container is not a DOM element -- tried everything

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Asking what seems to be a pretty common question, but I'm at my wit's end here. I had this project working a while ago (a few weeks), but returning to it I am stumped. I've been trying to pare down dependencies and unnecessary code to find the culprit.

I understand that this error means that I could be loading React before my html, but that's not the case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Funglr Ecommerce</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/admin.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

At this stage of setting up the project, I'm not quite sure how to properly debug things either. The 'App' is simple:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

// import custom components

class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <div>Hi! Test</div>
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Will post my various config files, as I suspect that may be the culprit?:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.11",
    "graphql": "^0.12.3",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.3",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }


module.exports = {
entry: {
    service: './client/service/service.index.js',
    admin: './client/admin/admin.index.js'
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/static'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
},
```

}

And .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Editing the `webpack.config.js` file eventually fixed the issue. Changing the loaders section to the following seemed to work:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
    ],
},
```